# Fixing imageswap onclick function

Tags: javascript

I currently have a working image swap code.  But I do not want to image swap all images. If want to be able to only swap orange images with each other. And if an orange image is swapped with either a blue or red image to make the orange identical to either the red or blue without affecting the red or blue one. Here is a sample [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezUQL/)

code that needs to be worked on

```
var pix = document.getElementById("GALLERY").getElementsByTagName("img");
for ( var p = 0; p < pix.length; ++p )
{
pix[p].onclick = picclick;
}

var firstImage = null;
function picclick( )
{
// to cancel a swap, click on first image again:
if ( firstImage == this ) 
{
    this.className = "normal";
    firstImage = null;
    return;
}
// is this first image clicked on?
if ( firstImage == null )
{
    // yes
    firstImage = this;
    this.className = "highlighted";
    document.getElementById('search').value = "";
    return; // nothing more to do
}
// aha! second image clicked on, so do swap
firstImage.className = "normal";
var temp = this.src;
this.src = firstImage.src;
firstImage.src = temp;
firstImage = null;

};
```

P.S. red and blue cannot be swapped with each other also.

What I have tried so far:

I have been trying if `1st_image_clicked=sold.png` then `2nd_image_clicked=sold.png` or  if `1st_image_clicked=0-1.png` and `2nd_image_clicked=sold.png` then `1st_imagec_licked & 2nd_image_clicked=sold.png`

Comment: Show what you have tried, explain what failed, and either improve your wording or give an example. Consider [event bubbling](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow).

Comment: I thought I made this clear as possible with example. Well I am not sure what I need. I have been trying if `1st_image_clicked=sold.png` then `2nd_image_clicked=sold.png` or  if `1st_image_clicked=0-1.png` and `2nd_image_clicked=sold.png` then `1st_imagec_licked & 2nd_image_clicked=sold.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly this is what you are looking for:

```
function picclick() {
    // to cancel a swap, click on first image again:
    if (firstImage == this) {
        this.className = "normal";
        firstImage = null;
        return;
    }
    // is this first image clicked on?
    if (firstImage == null) {
        // yes
        firstImage = this;
        this.className = "highlighted";
        //document.getElementById('search').value = "";
        return; // nothing more to do
    }
    // aha! second image clicked on, so do swap
    firstImage.className = "normal";
    //check if its not blue and red
    if (!(firstImage.alt == 'sold' && this.alt == 'payed') && !(firstImage.alt == 'payed' && this.alt == 'sold')) {
        if (firstImage.alt == 'sold' || firstImage.alt == 'payed') {
            //if first is blue or red, change second
            this.src = firstImage.src;
            this.alt = firstImage.alt;
        } else if (this.alt == 'sold' || this.alt == 'payed') {
            //if second is blue or red, change first
            firstImage.src = this.src;
            firstImage.alt = this.alt;
        } else {
            //do swap
            var temp = this.src;
            var temp2 = this.alt;
            this.src = firstImage.src;
            this.alt = firstImage.alt;
            firstImage.src = temp;
            firstImage.alt = temp2;
        }
    }
    firstImage = null;
};
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ezUQL/2/)**